# Reboot and zero drive

Tags: block-device, data-destruction

Is it possible to issue one command that will both reboot, boot to an external live drive or something similar, and then zero a hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without some prep work ahead of time.

You've got several things in play here:

1. Alternate boot
2. Boot media
3. Automated wipe
4. Execute with a single command

Without more details about what your environment I can't say what will work for you. But here's one scenario.

Create some type of live image, either CD, USB or alternate partition. If it's a partition you'll want to make it work like a live read-only image so that it doesn't depend on the fixed drive you're trying to replace. Add your preferred wiping command (e.g., `dd`) to the boot up scripts. Make sure it's inserted in at all times.

Configure Grub with so that the alternate boot media is available. Make sure it's not default. Write a script that will edit the grub config to switch the **destroyer of data** to default and immediately reboot. For Linux, `echo r > /proc/sysrq-trigger` is nice and merciless.

Anytime you're ready to nuke the system, execute that script as root. If you're willing to put in the effort up front, sure you can have a kill switch.

This is obviously *very dangerous* for your data.

Comment: Seems quite complex and out of my ability level.   
Thanks for the answer anyways.